# Appending numbers to a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
urllist = ['http://example.com',
           'http://example1.com']
i = 0
while i < len(urllist):
    source = urllib.urlopen(urllist[i]).read()
    regex = '(\d{3})/">(\w+\s-\s\w+)</a>'  # e.g. '435', 'Tom-Jerry' 
    p = re.compile(regex)
    db = re.findall(p, source)
    db = [tuple(filter(None, t)) for t in db]   

    hero_id = []
    for j in db:
        hero_id.append(j[0])

    i += 1
print hero_id
```

Note that: `db = [tuple(filter(None, t)) for t in db]`  `db` is a list of tuples like this: `[('564', 'Tom', 'Jerry'), ('321', 'X-man', 'Hulk')]`. Up the the `hero_id = []` line everything works like a charm. The for foop needs to append every number (from every url from the `urllist`). It does partly its job. At the end `hero_id` list contains only numbers from the last url (the previous numbers are gone). Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you set hero_id to an empty list at every iteration in the 'while' (`hero_id = []`)

Place that just after `i = 0`

Or you can simplify the code like so:

```
urllist = ['http://example.com', 'http://example1.com']
hero_id = []
for url in urllist:
    db = re.findall('(\d{3})/">(\w+\s-\s\w+)</a>', urllib.urlopen(url).read(), re.DOTALL)
    for j in db:
        hero_id.append(tuple(filter(None, j))[0])
print hero_id
```

Comment: Using the `requests` library, or sticking to the stdlib, using `urllib2.urlopen` instead would be a good idea...

Comment: requests are not really necesarry unless you need to send aditional data to that url or use or proxy or other advanced settings, and while I agree that urllib2 is better then urllib, this is nutship's decision, not mine.

Answer (score 1):

Since your hero_id is set in the while loop, it is over written at every iteration.
Make your hero_id variable global and do not reset it.

```
hero_id = []
while ():
    #your code
```

Comment: Scoping really has nothing to do with this.  Python doesn't create a new scope with blocks, only with functions.

Comment: ah yes. Since the outer declaration was not shown in the code, I got a little confused. Changed the answer. Thank you.